# How to avoid using this in a constructor

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have this situation:

```
interface MessageListener
{
   void onMessageReceipt(Message message);
}

class MessageReceiver
{
  MessageListener listener;
  public MessageReceiver(MessageListener listener, other arguments...)
  {
     this.listener = listener;
  }

  loop()
  {
    Message message = nextMessage();
    listener.onMessageReceipt(message);
  }
}
```

and I want to avoid the following pattern: (Using the this in the Client constructor)

```
class Client implements MessageListener
{
   MessageReceiver receiver;
   MessageSender sender;

  public Client(...)
  {
    receiver = new MessageReceiver(this, other arguments...);
    sender = new Sender(...);
  }
  .
  .
  .
  @Override
  public void onMessageReceipt(Message message)
  {
     if(Message.isGood())
       sender.send("Congrtulations");
     else
       sender.send("Boooooooo");
  }
}
```

The reason why i need the above functionality is because i want to call the sender inside the onMessageReceipt() function, for example to send a reply. But I dont want to pass the sender into a listener, so the only way I can think of is containing the sender in a class that implements the listener, hence the above resulting Client implementation. Is there a way to achive this without the use of 'this' in the constructor? It feels bizare and i dont like it, since i am passing myself to an object(MessageReceiver) before I am fully constructed. On the other hand, the MessageReceiver is not passed from outside, it is constructed inside, but does this 'purifies' the bizarre pattern?
I am seeking for an alternative or an assurance of some kind that this is safe, or situations on which it might backfire on me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Client`'s dependencies (such as `MessageReceiver`) could be injected into it rather than having the `Client` know how to construct the `MessageReceiver`:

```
Client client = new Client(...);
MessageReceiver rcvr = new MessageReceiver(client, ...);
client.setMessageReceiver(rcvr);
```

However I would suggest looking into breaking the circular dependency between these two classes, it sounds as if something is off in your design.

The real reason why passing `this` to another class in the first class's constructor is a bad practice is because you are allowing a reference to `this` to escape before it is fully constructed.

Comment: Hmmm... Maybe do what you suggest in a static factory method for creating a Client. Nice. I ll try it.
As far as the circular dep, it is intuitive because Client uses(contains) the receiver to get messages and also IS a listener since it processes the messages, thus becoming a listener.

Comment: Perhaps it is a naming thing but "receiver" and "listener" sound like synonyms here to me

Comment: You are right. Listener could be named Handler or Processor. It would be more clear then.

Answer (score 2):

It wont backfire on you as long as `this` is never referenced before construction. However, you should never rely on that assumption. Concurrency is a big factor here, as well as the contract for the code you pass it to.

Since Client **is** a MessageReceiver, why not make it one?

```
public Client extends MessageReceiver implements MessageListener{
    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: This was my first implementation but i will need to decouple how the Client 'handles' the messages(this is application logic) from how the client 'receives' them(this could be JMS, Rabbit, or totally other way).

Answer (score 1):

I don't see where the MessageReceiver is used, so at the moment you could write the code without MessageReceiver like this and it would be effectively the same:

```
interface MessageListener
{
    void onMessageReceipt(Message message);
}

class Client implements MessageListener
{
    MessageSender sender;

    public Client(...)
    {
        sender = new Sender(...);
    }
    .
    .
    .
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceipt(Message message)
    {
        if(Message.isGood())
            sender.send("Congrtulations");
        else
            sender.send("Boooooooo");
    }
}
```

I think a standard publish-subscribe or Observer pattern is probably what you need - but it's hard to tell without understanding the subtleties of the problem that you are trying to solve.

Comment: MessageReceiver calls the onMessageReceipt() method of a MessageListener that you pass to the MessageReceiver. So in your solution i must pass the Client to the MessageReceiver since my client is a listener too, which is effectively what I already do.

Comment: MessageReceiver.loop() calls the MessageListener.onMessageReceipt() method, but it isn't clear how the loop() method is called. The MessageReceiver isn't visible from outside of Client - at least not in any of the code shown so far.

Comment: the loop is called externally when want to start/resume receiving messages

Comment: So MessageReceiver is visible outside of Client?

Comment: No. client starts the receiver loop. The conditions that trigger the client to start the receiver loop can be external, e.g. a public method of the client, that in its implementation starts the receiver's loop.